# Prolog DCG illustration please

Tags: prolog, grammar, dcg

Currently I am playing with DCG in Prolog to parse an XML file. I was able to get the following code snippet which is able to parse a simple XML such as:

```
<author> <name> <f> arthur </f>
        <m> conan </m>
        <l> doyle </l>
     </name>
     <bday> <d> 22 </d>
        <m> 5  </m>
        <y> 1859 </y>
     </bday>
</author>

<author> <name> <f> william </f>
        <l> shakespeare </l>
     </name>
     <bday> <d> 23 </d>
        <m> 4  </m>
        <y> 1564 </y>
     </bday>
</author>
$
```

and the DCG is defined as:

```
xml([E]) --> element(E).
xml([E|L]) --> element(E), xml(L).

element(E) -->  begintag(N), elements(L), endtag(N), {E =.. [N|L]}.

elements(L) --> xml(L).
elements([E]) --> [E].

begintag(N) --> ['<', N, '>'].
endtag(N) -->   ['<', '/', N, '>'].
```

Would someone please illustrate how the DCG works in this case? I am having a really hard time trying to understand the arguments in the DCG (e.g. [E] in xml([E]); [E|L] in xml([E|L]). )
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think declaratively: A DCG always describes a list. In a DCG body, comma (",") is read as "and then". So for example, xml//1 describes (by its first rule) either a single element, or (by its second rule) an element *and then* something that is again described by xml//1. element//1 is a begintag, then elements, then an endtag etc. The arguments used in the DCG heads let you relate the sequence that is described by the DCG bodies to other information, like a subsequence you are particularly interested in. Take for example begintag//1 - you can ask:

```
?- phrase(begintag(T), [<, test, >]).
T = test.
```

and also in the other direction:

```
?- phrase(begintag(test), Ls).
Ls = [<, test, >].
```

In the case of begintag//1, the tag name seems to be important to you, so you have introduced an argument for it that, on the one hand, lets you generate an opening tag with a given name, and, on the other hand, lets you parse a tag and extract its name, and, on the third hand, ask even the most general query:

```
?- phrase(begintag(T), Ls).
Ls = [<, T, >].
```

which abstractly relates an opening XML tag to its name.

Comment: Thanks Mat! Do you have any tips on building the parse tree? I find it very hard to understand it even with 'trace' turned on, and it's even harder to come up with an idea to build the parse tree(i.e. return the parse tree after recognizing).